# How to show longitude and altitude on map in Android?

Tags: java, android

i have a place coordinate, i mean altitude and longitude , and i want to show this place with google map in android application, so how can i use this altitude and longitude to pass in a function and show that place in the app, i don't need to show current place , i have this longitudes and altitudes from before,and i save theme as a string in my application , is there any function or layout to show this place with this coordinates in application ? or i have to use some different method to show this places on map?

Comment: @HareshChhelana what's the marker?how can i use this?

Comment: Check : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Answer (score 0):

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ lattitude string  +"," + longitude_string +"("+ "Hello location" + ")&iwloc=A&hl=es";     
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

This will open google maps with whatever coordinates you provide.